# Drupal 7 Computed field in field collection

Tags: drupal-7, timestamp, computed-field, drupal-field-collection

I have a field collection with 2 dates (Timestamp) and would like to calculate the difference between the dates. But I can't get it to work.. Any help?

```
Computed code:
$eind = $entity_field->field_data_field_eind_field_collection_item_entity_type[0]'timestamp'];
$begin = $entity_field->field_data_field_begin_field_collection_item_entity_type[0]['timestamp'];
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $eind - $begin;

Display code:
$display_output = $entity_field[0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the `[` on `['timestamp']`

```
$eind = $entity_field->field_data_field_eind_field_collection_item_entity_type[0]['timestamp']; // missing the [ here
```

Comment: Oh I see.. But when I add [ it still gives me this error:

    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (li